# Rotate Rectangular Canvas Image to Fit

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am attempting to rotate an image that fills a rectangular canvas element.  Using the code below, I can rotate it satisfactorily (90 degree increments).  However, when the big side is translated to the small side, I cannot figure out how to fill the entire canvas.  Instead, I have a compacted image.  Any help would be appreciated in solving this.  Thanks!

What I have so far:

```
var degrees = 90;

function drawRotated(degrees){


    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var translateX = (canvas.width)/2;
    var translateY = (canvas.height)/2;
    ctx.translate(translateX,translateY);
    ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);
    ctx.translate(-translateX,-translateY);
    ctx.drawImage(theImage, 0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to rotate the image without distorting it, it is important to use the image dimensions to translate the image to `0, 0`. this will get the center of the image to the origin. you `rotate` the matrix around the origin (`0, 0`). *you were rotating around the center of the canvas.*

additionally you have to perform some math for one translation so that the image is always in the upper left corner.

```
function drawRotated(degrees){
    var theImage = document.getElementById('image');
    var imageWidth = theImage.naturalWidth;
    var imageHeight = theImage.naturalHeight;

    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var angle = degrees*Math.PI/180;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // this will align your image in the upper left corner when rotating in 90deg increments
    ctx.translate(Math.abs(imageWidth/2 * Math.cos(angle) + imageHeight/2 * Math.sin(angle)), Math.abs(imageHeight/2 * Math.cos(angle) + imageWidth/2 * Math.sin(angle)));
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    ctx.translate(-imageWidth/2, -imageHeight/2);
    ctx.drawImage(theImage, 0, 0);
}
```

see [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k4rp72tg/)

Comment: I believe I understand what is happening here, but I still am having an issue scaling the rotated image from your example to the existing canvas.  For instance, if I rotate an image of notebook paper lying horizontally with "hello" in the left corner, it will be zoomed in on "hello".  I would have thought scaling would have been done with a simple ctx.drawImage(theImage,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height) but that doesnt work.  Any suggestions?  Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: transform the matrix to scale the image with `ctx.scale(xScale, yScale)`. apply this transformation before the other ones. see [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k4rp72tg/1/)